# Detect QRCode with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, qr-code

Im trying to use OpenCV to detect a QR-Code in a Image. As an Example, i downloaded a basic QR-Code from here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:QRCodeWikipedia.png, or the direct link is this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cb/QRCodeWikipedia.png

What i did is downloading OpenCV 4.5.5. for Windows directly here: https://opencv.org/releases/, and add the include/lib dirs into my project.

Now, my code wont detect the QR-Code, and then wont decode it. But if i hold my phone over it, it detect it without problems, so i guess the QRCode itself is ok.

The imshow at the end also works fine, so the file get correctly loaded and displayed.

Thats my code:

```cpp
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Mat getImage = imread(R"(QRCodeWikipedia.png)");

    QRCodeDetector qrDet = QRCodeDetector::QRCodeDetector();

    Mat corners;
    bool detection_result = qrDet.detect(getImage, corners);
    std::cout << "detection_result: " << detection_result << std::endl;

    Mat points, rectImage;
    std::string data = qrDet.detectAndDecode(getImage, points, rectImage);
    if (data.length() > 0) {
        std::cout << "Data after decoding: " << data << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "QR Code not detected" << std::endl;
    }

    imshow("file", getImage);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

Output from that code is

> detection_result: 0

> QR Code not detected

Is there something im doing wrong? Or should be changed, so it can detect that QR-Code?

Comment: yes. the image has no "quiet zone", which is required for QR codes. use a different image or pad this one with white.

Comment: 5 months later I see this comment and it solves my problem. Thanks @ChristophRackwitz ! I forgot the quiet zone in my Python QR detector.